# Creating a webserver of a Windows XP computer?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, website

I want to create a webserver for my website since what I'm going to have on the website is far more than I can store web hotel.  I have this XP computer I'd like to use as a server.

I did have a guide of this but unfortunately the link is broken. But what I understood was that I'd be in need of a Windows 2000 disc for this to work.

Do you have any good tutorials/guides about how I can remake my XP computer to a webserver?

The computer is running Windows XP home edition Service Pack 2

Comment: Wipe it and install Linux on it.

Comment: You don't need a Windows 2000 disk to run Windows XP. I'm not really sure what that has to do with anything... The main thing you will need to run a server, though, is a persistent (always on) Internet connection and an ISP that won't cancel your account for running a server. Make sure that you have those two things first, before trying to set up a computer.

Comment: @Paul: Not necessarily a good idea if he/she has never used Linux before... But certainly worth considering.

Comment: @Cody; If you're running a server and you've never done so before, you're going to be learning anything. You may as well learn how to do it *right* from the start.

Comment: @Phoshi: Fascinating how running Linux on your server equates to "doing it right". I'm not sure I agree with that particular assumption.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Well, some Windows versions' EULAs prohibit use as a server, IIRC (XP Home? or maybe it was some OEM version of it? I don't know, it's been a while since I last installed WinXP). Apart from that, yeah, use whatever fits the bill; e.g. ASP.NET looks useful (see this site, for example ;)).

Comment: @Piskvor: I don't believe that's correct. There is an issue of client access licenses (CALs), but that doesn't apply to web servers (which appears to be the goal here). I've never seen a Windows EULA that prohibited running a web server. Granted, Windows XP Home Edition doesn't include any server software, but there's nothing in the license to prohibit you from installing such software and using it as a web server.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Aha. I seem to be thoroughly confused about the issue then; thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Cody; Well, I've found linux servers to be, on the whole, much more reliable. And how, precisely, are you supposed to administrate *anything* using cmd of all things?

Comment: @Phoshi: Lose the fanboy-ism. I'm tired of Linux users assuming Windows sucks because they don't know how to use it. That's no better than when Windows users do it about Linux. You can do *almost* anything with `cmd` that you can do with other shells. But the real point is that you don't. Windows provides graphical management tools that are a real boon to the *inexperienced* admin, much like the OP. Alternatively, you could ditch the GUI altogether and use PowerShell. Guaranteed to beat the pants off bash and tcsh. Newer versions of Windows Server even have a Core install without a GUI.

Comment: @Phoshi: And for the record, I've been a sys admin for both platforms. I know each of them quite well. Windows isn't *necessarily* my preference either. (No one's mentioned BSD; it sure isn't Linux.) My thought is simply that a Windows user might be more comfortable administering (learning to administer) a Windows-based server than they would be learning a whole new OS. And additionally, that there's nothing *wrong* with a Windows-based server. Stack Overflow et. al. work pretty well, and they're an entirely MS-based shop.

Comment: @Cody; I didn't say windows server didn't work, I said that I'd found linux servers to be more reliable and require next to no upkeep. Regardless, it was meant to be a joke, not the start of an argument about personal preferences, those *never* go well.

Comment: @Phoshi: Neither do jokes that look like it.

Comment: @Sweppi As an aside: XP is at SP3 now - apply the update.

Comment: @JanDoggen [Windows XP was EOL'd (reached its end of life) in 2009](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP#Support_lifecycle) and extended support ends in half a year now, in April 2014.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to do it.

Your question states about [Windows Server](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/default.aspx]) disk. This is an different operating system and will remove your Windows XP.

There are many differences between Windows client and Windows Server, however, unless the site you are going to make will be "big", I would not recommend you go down this route as there are costs involved.

However, if you are going to be programming ASP/Asp.Net you will need to either upgrade to XP Pro, or get a server edition. The Windows XP built in Web Server is restricted, but does work well.

However, if you want PHP or simply static HTML, you can stay with Windows XP and take a look at [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), it is a single installer that will have you up and running in no time!

Simply put your content in a folder and it will be accessible to anyone via http://your.ip.address

I don't understand what you mean by web hotel.

If this is publicly accessible to the internet, you need to forward port 80 from your router to your machine. If it is a single internal network and you do not want outside access... if you do not set a firewall up, it should work on your internal address.

If you want a friendly name, you have two choices - if you have an internal DNS server, set up an additional entry with the name that points to your ip. However, it is probably easier if you already own a domain name, just to set one up with the ip of your external address (if you forward port 80) or just your internal address - if you only want people from inside the network to access. (This will simply time out for other people).

Hope this helps, and I know you will have follow up questions, this is not very straight forward, but feel free to ask and I will try to help you!

Answer (score 2):

> *Do you have any good tutorials/guides about how I can remake my xp computer to a server?*

Microsoft limited the ability to run IIS on XP to the "professional" version.

> *The computer is running windows xp home edition Service Pack 2*

Home edition is limited even further in that you cannot install IIS on any home edition of XP.

Your solution will be to upgrade to a professional version of XP, upgrade to a professional or enterprise version of Vista or 7, or upgrade to a server operating system such as Server 2003 or 2008. Installing Linux is another option, and if you wish to run php web pages, a better option than sticking with a Microsoft operating system.

Comment: Re "Microsoft limited the ability to run IIS on XP to the "professional" version." - Consider the security holes in the IIS version that comes with Windows XP...

Comment: Re: Upgrading to Windows 7. Make sure you download, install, and run the free [Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/get/upgrade-advisor.aspx) utility program from Microsoft beforehand to make sure your PC is capable of running it.

Comment: There are tricks to install IIS under XP Home, and IIRC that's what the Win2000 disk was necessary for - although I never got it to work and switched to WAMP.